# ¿Por qué no puedo crear diagramas para mi base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero generar un diagrama de mi base de datos. SQL Server Management Studio no me permite crear los diagramas, al seleccionar la opción me sale el siguiente mensaje de error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Texto del mensaje de error:

> Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does not have a valid owner. To continue, first use the Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement to set the database owner to a valid login, then add the database diagram support objects.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio @yesica. Por favor considera explicar más tu problema y proveer texto en lugar de imágenes. Asimismo, intenta que el título de las preguntas sean lo más descriptivo y concreto posibles para entender tu problema o parte de él al momento de leerlo. Esto beneficia a la comunidad al momento de apoyarte y a los futuros lectores de la pregunta y respuestas.

Comment: Al parecer tu problema es por el usuario que utilizas para conectarte a la base de datos. Necesitas acceder con un usuario que tenga los permisos necesarios o brindarle el permiso adecuado con el comando `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` tal como te indica en el mensaje.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte

Comment: realice los pasos que me indicaba el error que me aparecía pero no me permite realizar la autorización, no me aparece la opción

Comment: Intenta acceder a tu base de datos con un usuario con más privilegios como `sa`.

Answer (score 2):

-- remplazar MiBasedeDatos en el script

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MiBasedeDatos TO sa
GO
```

---

Luego

```
Select your database >> Right Click >> Select Properties

Select FILE in left side of page
```

> In the OWNER box, select button which has three dots (…) in it
>   Now select user ‘sa’ or NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and click OK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso te debe funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te aconsejaría que ingreses a las propiedades de tu Base de Datos desde el Management Studio, (Click derecho a la BD y click en Propiedades) luego vayas a la ficha de Archivos, y en la opción Propietario, lo cambies por el sa y con ello podrás acceder al diagrama de tu Base de Datos.

Answer (score 0):

ese es un error muy comun cuando el owner de la base es distinto.
Proba con esto

USE [TU BASE]
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'SA';

Answer (score 0):

Para poder resolver esto haremos lo siguientes pero antes de ello es recomendable revisar el usuario que estas usando y que tengo los permisos pertinentes y reiniciar sqlserver si el problema persiste lo resolveremos de la siguiente manera:
Abrir el SQL Server Management
0. Explorador de objetos
1. Click derecho sobre base da tados.
2. Click en Propiedades (Properties) en el menu emergente.
3. Click en Files
4. Ahy en Owner(debajo de Data Base Name) dar click al cuadrito de 3 puntos del lado derecho.
5. El el siguiente cuadro "Select Database Owner" click en Browse...
6. El el siguiente cuadro "Browse for Objects" click en salilla de SA
7. Ok a todo.
8. En el Explorador de objetos ubicar la base, dar click al signo de +.
9. Escoger opcion, Database Diagramas -> Click derecho New Database Diagramas. (posiblemente a algunos le vuelva a salir un mensaje. No tomarlo encuenta y repetir el paso 9).
10. Deve Aparecer un aventana de trabnajo con las bases de datos existentes.
Link(http://www.forosdelweb.com/f87/no-puede-crear-diagrama-entidad-relacion-sql-server-1052029/)

Otra opcion para resolver esto es modificando los permisos y esto se puede hacer asi:
http://devtroce.com/2012/07/27/solucionar-error-alter-authorization-para-crear-diagramas-en-sql-server/